# Sort svn tags based on creation date

Tags: java, windows, svn, tortoisesvn

Is it possible to get the svn tags sorted based on creation date.

Current command which we use is

```
svn --non-interactive list URL
```

This is returning the tags sorted based on tag name.
Is there any way we could get tags based on creation date.

Answer (score 0):

Subversion itself does not do this. Tags themselves are nothing special to Subversion - they're just copies, and any significance to comes from the naming and usage convention that you apply to them.

Assuming your tags are static (they don't change once created), you'll have to get the list of all of the directories, run `svn info` on each one to extract `Last Changed Rev` (or `Last Changed Date`), and collect into a hashtable or similar data structure, then sort that.

If your tags are *not* static, then you'll have to go spelunking through the log itself, using `--stop-on-copy` (the `--xml` option is probably going to be helpful for parsing) to find the first log entry for each tag.